# Android Spinner Footer

Tags: android, spinner, footer

Is there a way to add a footer inside a spinner drop down list? For instance, say I am populating a spinner from a database, but I want a selection at the bottom of the list regardless of how I arrange the list. The list might be "Database Item 1, 2.., 3..." and at the bottom of the list a footer choice of "Add Item to Database."

So far I have used your CustomSpinner class as follows:

```
public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner implements OnItemClickListener {

private AlertDialog myDialog = null;
private OnClickListener myButtonClickListener = null;
private GrainSpinnerAdapter adapter = null;

public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setButtonClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    myButtonClickListener = listener;
}

public void setAdapter(GrainSpinnerAdapter adapter){
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    Context context = getContext();

    //Inflate the layout
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_spinner, null);

    // set up list view
    final ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setSelection(getSelectedItemPosition());
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    // set up button
    final Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(myButtonClickListener);

    // build our dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    // show prompt, just as our Spinner parent does
    if (getPrompt() != null) {
        builder.setTitle(getPrompt());
    }

    // create and show dialog
    myDialog = builder.setView(v).create();
    myDialog.show();

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View itemView, int position, long id) {
    setSelection(position);
    if (myDialog != null) {
        myDialog.dismiss();
        myDialog = null;
    }

}
```

}
I am wanting to use a separate adapter such as this:

```
public class GrainListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private static final String DEFAULT_UNITS = "American";
private Button upButton;
private Context myContext;
private RecipeGrainActivity parentActivity;
private Button downButton;
private String units;
private double getLbs;

public GrainListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    myContext = context;
    parentActivity = (RecipeGrainActivity) myContext;

    //Checks for metric pref.
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    units = String.valueOf(myPrefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.pref_measurement), DEFAULT_UNITS));
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
    final int getId = cursor.getInt(idColumn);
    final double increment = 0.25;

    UnitsConversions convert = new UnitsConversions();

    int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    String getName = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainName);
    name.setText(getName);

    int originColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("origin");
    String getOrigin = cursor.getString(originColumn);
    TextView origin = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainOrigin);
    origin.setText(getOrigin);

    if(units.equals("Metric")){
        //Sets labels to metric.
        String kilos = context.getResources().getString (R.string.kilograms);
        TextView weightLabel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainLbsLabel);
        weightLabel.setText(kilos);
    }


}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.grain_list_item, null);
    return view;
}
```

}

Which allows me to build a custom row for each listitem in the spinner. I was thinking I could set the adapter to the CustomSpinner using the customspinner.setadapter() within my activity. However, the ListView defined in the CustomSpinner class uses an adapter referenced within the class. How do I pass my adapter into the class so it can use it?

Here is how I had to add the custom item to my layout:

```
<com.bluelightuniverse.android.brewmobile.CustomSpinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/GrainNameSpinner"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GrainOriginSpinner"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/AddGrainButton">
</com.bluelightuniverse.android.brewmobile.CustomSpinner>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experimenting with making more complex views in Spinners' dialogs.

To do what you've explained, I made a subclass of `Spinner`. I examined the **[source](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java)** of the Android Spinner and overrided the `performClick` to do essentially what you want: populate your own dialog with a custom view.

```
package me.ribose.example; // you'll have to change this

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner implements OnItemClickListener {
    private AlertDialog mDialog = null;
    private OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = null;

    public UnitSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setButtonClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        mButtonClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        Context context = getContext();

        // get the set adapter
        final DropDownAdapter adapter = new DropDownAdapter(getAdapter());

        // inflate our layout
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customSpinner, null);

        // set up list view
        final ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setSelection(getSelectedItemPosition());
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // set up button
        final Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);

        // build our dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        // show prompt, just as our Spinner parent does
        if (getPrompt() != null) {
            builder.setTitle(getPrompt());
        }

        // create and show dialog
        mDialog = builder.setView(v).create();
        mDialog.show();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view,
                            View itemView, int position, long id) {
        setSelection(position);
        if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
            mDialog = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>Wrapper class for an Adapter. Transforms the embedded Adapter instance
     * into a ListAdapter.</p>
     */
    private static class DropDownAdapter implements ListAdapter, SpinnerAdapter {
        private SpinnerAdapter mAdapter;

        /**
         * <p>Creates a new ListAddapter wrapper for the specified adapter.</p>
         *
         * @param adapter the Adapter to transform into a ListAdapter
         */
        public DropDownAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
            this.mAdapter = adapter;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mAdapter == null ? 0 : mAdapter.getCount();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mAdapter == null ? null : mAdapter.getItem(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return mAdapter == null ? -1 : mAdapter.getItemId(position);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return mAdapter == null ? null :
                    mAdapter.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return mAdapter != null && mAdapter.hasStableIds();
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
            }
        }

        /**
         * <p>Always returns false.</p>
         *
         * @return false
         */
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * <p>Always returns false.</p>
         *
         * @return false
         */
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return true;
        }

        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return getCount() == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need my customSpinner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px"
            android:cacheColorHint="@null"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </ListView>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add to Database">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Of course, make that `android:text` a string resource.

More words on this: Just make a `CustomSpinner` in your activity's layout as you need it and call `setButtonClickListener` (probably near where you set the adapter) to add a callback for your button, that perhaps prompts the user to add or whatever you need. And of course `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after adding to the database. Everything that works on a Spinner should work exactly the same with this custom spinner.

Side note (UPDATED): You will have to make sure your adapter's list items have black text (ex: `android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light_nodisable"`)! I changed the XML above so it doesn't require white background on items (which then makes item highlights not work).

---

Code notes: Since the people who made Android decided to not make an easy way to customize spinner dialogs (hard-coded use of `AlertDialog.Builder` using `setSingleChoiceItems()` as well as a private class to "convert" `SpinnerAdapter`s to `ListAdapter`s), I had to copy their entire inner class to get the desired effect. Also note they are bad documenters (see `DropDownAdapter`.`isEnabled`/`areAllItemsEnabled` for the laugh of the day!).

Comment: Your code looks intriguing, thank you for spending the time explaining that. Its gonna take me some time to see if it works for my needs. So, just so I understand...I am building a custom spinner, and the listview is going to contain my database items as it normally would, then I am using a button on the bottom of the list as my custom item? I like this because I should also be able to change the look of the button to stand out from the other items in the list. Currently I am using a custom SimpleCursorAdapter to populate my spinner. Can I still use that as opposed to the DropDownAdapter?

Comment: Absolutely! Use any adapter you wish and pass it to custom spinner.setAdapter(yourAdapter). The DropDownAdapter private class is just to make a SpinnerAdapter -> ListAdapter, exactly as the Android source code currently does.  So anything you can pass Spinner.setAdapter() you can pass this.

Comment: Oh, no you aren't using the DropDownAdapter directly. This subclass is basically meant to not require changes (but you can add more things like more buttons on the bottom by changing the layout and adding a click handler). Check out the [android source code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java) to see its an exact copy to work around their hard-to-customizable spinner.

Comment: Edit: I've got the spinner working properly, but its not showing my custom spinner row anymore. I'll update my question as I make progress.

Comment: The adapter variable referenced inside the spinner is the same one you set using setAdapter(). The `getAdapter()` call inside performClick calls the Spinner (super) .getAdapter() (maybe I should make that more clear...).   So does `customadapter.setAdapter(grainlistadapter)` not work??

Answer (score 8):

in your CursorAdapter , Override the methods getCount() and getDropDownView:
By example , if you want to put a button at the end , you can do this:

```
new SimpleCursorAdapter(...) {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return super.getCount()+1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View res=null;
            if (position == getCount()-1) {
                //better not try to reuse our view as it can be requested for the spinner or by the list with different kind of layouts.
                View mButton= getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_activity_button, parent,false);
                mButton.setOnClickListener(ObservationListFragment.this);
                res= mButton;
            } else if (convertView != null && android.R.id.button1 == convertView.getId() ){
             // If the adapter is trying to recycle our footer view, we force the generation of a new view (check on the id of our custom view)
                res= super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
            } else {
                res= super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            }
            return res;
        }
    };
```

Comment: If I do this using a CursorAdapter (not SimpleCursorAdapter) I get an error because it's trying to move the cursor to a position that doesn't exist. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What you might be able to do is use the [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge): this lets you create an adapter that takes in your database adapter and a static View (the button to add item to database) and set that as the Spinner view. I've used this for `ListView`s but not for `Spinner`s so it is uncertain if it will work but I think it will.