# How to add button to the footer of Spinner

Tags: android-layout, android, android-spinner, android-button

I have a spinner, I want to add a button "Cancel" to the end of spinner so when the user click it the selected element in the spinner doesn't change.

#### xml

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/s_signin_type"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:prompt="@string/s_type" />
```

#### Java Activity

```
Spinner s_type;
s_type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s_signin_type);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Data.types);
        adapterType
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s_type.setAdapter(adapterType);
```

[image]

thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not let the user simply dismiss the Spinner with the BACK button?

Comment: @Luksprog I really like to use the cancel button, It is more user friendly, plus I have a device with buttons not touch and many users have it, so It is harder to press `Back` rather than touch.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005265/android-spinner-footer)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to add button to spinner by overriding getDropDownView() method in ArrayAdapter. It goes something like this (I omitted view reusing, ...):

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
//items I want to display
items.add("1");
items.add("2");
//add placeholder for button
items.add(null);
...

ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items) {

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                //create view for placeholder
                if (getItem(position) == null) {
                    Button b = new Button(getActivity());
                    b.setText("Test");                  
                    return b;
                }
                //create view for standard spinner item
                return LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent,
                        false);
            }
```